# Google Analytics: insite links vs. outbound links

Tags: google-analytics, hyperlink, redirect, outbound

First I want to apology for the lame question. I am tracking custom events with Google Analytics and I am wondering if redirecting to another page in the same website should be timeout like the outbound links, or it is ok to have no delay.